# Simple inequality in euclidean $n$ space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Then

$$ |x_1| + ... + |x_n| \leq \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{ x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2} $$

Is this inequality true?

I have proved it for $n = 2$. For instance, it follows from the AM-GM inequality

$$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \geq xy \iff (x^2+y^2) \geq 2 xy \iff 2(x^2+y^2) \geq 2xy + x^2 + y^2 = (x+y)^2 \iff \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq x + y$$

But, how can I prove this for the $n$ case? Induction does not seem to work well. Any help would be gratly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Also known as the root-mean square inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$|x_1| +\cdots+|x_n| \le (|x_1|^2 +\cdots+|x_n|^2)(n)$$
$$(|x_1| +\cdots+|x_n|)^2 \le \sqrt{n}\sqrt{|x_1|^2 +\cdots+|x_n|^2}$$

I recall to have answered the exact same question somewhere before (in that answer I used QM-GM as an alternative)... ([found it!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678044/inequality-involving-absolute-values-and-square-roots/678078#678078))